# Checkbox State Behavior on Reload in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, browser, refresh

Hi, could someone please tell me why it is that when I refresh a page of my Rails app the checkboxes whose state are checked become unchecked in Chrome but not in Firefox. Therefore i am uncheked all these in document.ready function. Why is the behaviour of Firefox different from Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a page refresh, you are reloading the page.  There is no expectation that the *user* changes to the page since the page was originally loaded would persist.

Firefox has a browser vendor specific feature to try to remember user's selections.  It's not standard.

There is no fix for this.  You cannot get Firefox's non-standard behavior in a browser which did not also implement this feature.  The standard expectation is to lose all the edits from a page refresh.

However, if you have javascript setting the state when the page loaded the first time, try running it from window.load.

Answer (score 1):

Try autocomplete="off" works in IE :)